# Cant Add Values Assigned to Each CheckBox (VB)

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add values that are assigned to a specific check box. I have 3 checked boxes-- ansmach, calcu & copymach. I think I have figured out to compute for total when only one check box is ticked, but not when I have 2 or 3 ticked checkboxes. I wonder if anyone can help me check the code I have.  Here's my code.

```
Private Sub chkansmach_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkansmach.CheckedChanged
        ansmach = 7500
        calcu = 300
        copymach = 37600
        If chkansmach.Checked = True Then
            officetotal = ansmach
        ElseIf chkansmach.Checked = False Then
            officetotal = 0
        End If
        total = comptotal + officetotal + peritotal
        txttotal.Text = total
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkcalcu_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkcalcu.CheckedChanged
        ansmach = 7500
        calcu = 300
        copymach = 37600
        If chkcalcu.Checked = True Then
            officetotal = calcu
        ElseIf chkcalcu.Checked = False Then
            officetotal = 0
        End If
        total = comptotal + officetotal + peritotal
        txttotal.Text = total
    End Sub

    Private Sub chkcopymach_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkcopymach.CheckedChanged
        ansmach = 7500
        calcu = 300
        copymach = 37600
        If chkcopymach.Checked = True Then
            officetotal = copymach
        ElseIf chkcopymach.Checked = False Then
            officetotal = 0
        End If
        total = comptotal + officetotal + peritotal
        txttotal.Text = total
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Then update your question with some details.  You said `ansmach, calcu & copymach` were checkboxes, but the code treats them as variables (whose declaration is not shown).  Also ask a concise question.

Comment: apologies for confusion.  ansmach, calcu and copymach are the values I assigned to checkboxes chkansmach, chkcalcu and chkcopymach.

Comment: Please re-read the comment carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a private function that checked the state of all 3 checkboxes and computed the total like this:

```
Private Sub HandleCheckBoxes() 
    Dim total = 0
    If chkansmach.Checked Then total += 7500
    If chkcalcu.Checked Then total += 300
    If chkcopymach.Checked Then total += 37600
    txttotal.Text = total.ToString()
End Sub
```

Then all 3 of your event handlers can just call this function.

Note that it's also possible to have one event handler for all 3 checkboxes.  Just use

```
Private Sub checkboxes_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkansmach.CheckChanged, chkcalcu.CheckChanged, chkcopymach.CheckChanged
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Every .NET control has a [Tag property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) which contains some lagniappe data specific to that control. What you could do is assign the Tag property (either in the designer or in the Form Load event). Then bind the CheckedChange events for all the CheckBox controls together and inside the event handler you'd increment your *total* variable by the Tag property value if the respective CheckBox is checked.

Here is a quick example where I set the Tag property in the Form Load event:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Assign the Tag property of each CheckBox
    chkansmach.Tag = 7500
    chkcalcu.Tag = 300
    chkcopymach.Tag = 37600
End Sub

'Bind all the CheckBox controls CheckChanged event together
Private Sub Checkbox_Changed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles chkansmach.CheckChanged, chkcalcu.CheckChanged, chkcopymach.CheckChanged
    'Create a variable to store the total
    Dim total As Integer = 0

    'If a CheckBox is Checked, increment the total variable by the respective CheckBox's Tag property
    If chkansmach.Checked Then
        total += CInt(chkansmach.Tag)
    End If
    If chkcalcu.Checked Then
        total += CInt(chkcalcu.Tag)
    End If
    If chkcopymach.Checked Then
        total += CInt(chkcopymach.Tag)
    End If

    'Display the total
    txttotal.Text = total.ToString()
End Sub
```